# InDesign - Can't see purple alignment lines in CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign

In InDesign CS5 I could draw a text box, drag it on page, and see purple lines that helped me align. Where did they go in CS6? I don't see them as I drag text boxes. Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ctrl-u` (or `cmd-u` on a mac).

This toggles `View > Grids & Guides > Smart guides`. Smart Guides are the purple lines that guide alignment to the page, and the green lines that guide alignment to objects.

There are also tick-box options controlling what the Smart Guides do and don't align to under `Preferences > Guides & Pasteboard`.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

If that doesn't make the red margin lines show up on screen, then go to "View → Overview Print View". Click that on and off. That got my margins to finally show up. Seems buggy, I know.

Comment: Please add a screenshot and which version do you use?

Answer (score -1):

Command U. I just had the same issue. I understand this was 7 years ago but no-one ever replied. Hope this could help someone in the future.

Comment: There are three anwsers, and the accepted one mentions your key combo. Also, since keys can be reassigned, this answer mentions the menu item to use as well.

Answer (score -2):

You could also try pressing the <kbd>W</kbd> key. Guides won't show if you're in preview mode.